# Chrome, Flexbox and fat div

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

Trying to understand flexbox better.

In Firefox this snippet correctly handles left column, but in Chrome right column is too wide and left is too skinny.

How can I make it work with Chrome?

```css
.child {
  border: solid 1px;
}
.left {
  width: 100px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child left">
    I'm left!
  </div>
  <div class="child right">
    And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat!
    And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and
    fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right
    and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm
    right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat! And I'm right and fat!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add `min-width: 100px` to `.left`

Comment: Okay, it worked. But why does simple `width` work in Firefox, and Chrome is demanding `min-width`?..

Comment: You could call it **freakin' browser quirks** for starters. For testing and development I would advise to use Firefox Developer Edition which is closests to W3 specs. And for the quirks, you just have to remember this solution as you will encounter it time and again... Tried IE yet? Ughhh. I actually have stopped using vendor prefixes. So far things work well. (autoprefixer is the best, BTW)

Comment: No kidding, a Delphi developer? Small world, my last job (A.D. 1653) was Delphi 7.x

Comment: Okay, thank you =-) One more reason for me to try and become backend coder, to be far away from this =-)

Comment: Yes, Delphi was my love in age of 14-18 =-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Firefox this snippet correctly handles left column, but in Chrome right column is too wide and left is too skinny.

It actually doesn't work in Firefox. The computed width of `.left` in FF is about 84px, not 100px.

[image]

And in Chrome it just shrinks to fit content.

Evidently, different browsers handle the default minimum size of flex items in their own way.

The cross-browser solution is to define [`flex-shrink`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-shrink/).

Instead of:

```
.left { width: 100px; }
```

Try:

```
.left { flex: 0 0 100px; } /* don't grow, don't shrink, width is 100px */
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/nct17z4g/1/)

Learn more about the `flex` property here:

- [MDN `flex` property definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)
- [CSS-Tricks `flex` property definition](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/)

Comment: Thank you very much! Did not notice that firefox shrinks column too =-)